# What Sanitizes Data From REST/Web APIs?

Tags: vb.net, api, rest

I have a REST Service built in vb.net running on IIS.  I've noticed that the returned data is sanitized or escaped, e.g.:

```
<script>alert('testing1')</script>
```

is returned as:

```
&lt;script&gt;alert('testing1')&lt;/script&gt;
```

Can anyone tell me what is doing the escaping, would it be .net or IIS and can it be switched on or off?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could have a controller method like this..

```
    Function ReturnJavascript() As Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage
        Dim resp As New Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        resp.Content = New Net.Http.StringContent("<script>alert('testing1')</script>", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain")
        Return resp
    End Function
```

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  If you don't want to return as a response message, you might attempt returning as content set to text/plain.